# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined (Full stack question)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typeerror

I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined when I try to add an item to my shopping cart with React. I am not sure what's happening exactly but think it has to do with how the data is being retrieved from the database. I am using MongoDB. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload'
import ProductInfo from '../DetailProductPage/Sections/ProductInfo'
import Axios from 'axios';
import { addToCart } from '../../../_actions/user_actions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "Africa" },
    { key: 2, value: "Europe" },
    { key: 3, value: "Asia" },
    { key: 4, value: "North America" },
    { key: 5, value: "South America" },
    { key: 6, value: "Australia" },
    { key: 7, value: "Antarctica" }
]

function UploadProductPage(props) {

    const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("")
    const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("")
    const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0)
    const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState(1)

    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])


    const onTitleChange = (event) => {
        setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onPriceChange = (event) => {
        setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
        setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const updateImages = (newImages) => {
        setImages(newImages)
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();


        if (!TitleValue || !DescriptionValue || !PriceValue ||
            !ContinentValue || !Images) {
            return alert('fill all the fields first!')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: props.user.userData._id,
            title: TitleValue,
            description: DescriptionValue,
            price: PriceValue,
            images: Images,
            continents: ContinentValue,
        }

        Axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('Product Successfully Uploaded')
                    props.history.push('/')
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload Product')
                }
            })
    }

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = props.match.params.productId
    const [Product, setProduct] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`/api/product/products_by_id?id=${productId}&type=single`)
            .then(response => {
                setProduct(response.data[0])
            })

    }, [])

    const addToCartHandler = (productId) => {
        dispatch(addToCart(productId))
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        setProduct(props.detail)

    }, [props.detail])

    const addToCarthandler = () => {
        props.addToCart(props.detail._id)
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2}> Upload Travel Product</Title>
            </div>


            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} >

                {/* DropZone */}
                <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />

                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onTitleChange}
                    value={TitleValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <TextArea
                    onChange={onDescriptionChange}
                    value={DescriptionValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Price($)</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onPriceChange}
                    value={PriceValue}
                    type="number"
                />
                <br /><br />
                <select onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}>
                    {Continents.map(item => (
                        <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value} </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />

                <Button 
                    onClick={function(event){onSubmit(event); addToCarthandler()}}
                    addToCart={addToCartHandler}
                    detail={productId}>
                    Submit
                </Button>

            </Form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

Getting these errors in console:

```
xhr.js:155 GET http://localhost:3000/api/product/products_by_id?id=undefined&type=single 400 (Bad Request)
```

```
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

Any help would be great. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Comment: please be more specific. what line does it happen? What exactly is starting the execution? And so on.

Comment: Hello Pedro, I updated with the errors I am seeing in the console. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
props.user.userData._id,
```

or 
`props.detail._id`
are wrong 
you can use console.log to check which item "props.user.userData" or props.detail"
does not have the property _id.

Note: You can also use "?." operator to remove this error but that may cause the logic issue.

Another problem is In the API call. you are getting 
const productId = props.match.params.productId;
productId as undefined and you are passing undefined in the URL.

Comment: is there a simple fix to getting the API call to work?

Comment: You can check why you are getting "productId" undefined in props.match.params.productId. then it will work fine.
You can also test your API by giving a hard-coded value to in place of variable "productId" to check if route is working fine or not.